# Como faço pra tirar a seta de voltar do React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Meu código no `App.js`:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>

        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ title: "Bem-vindo!"}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Fmenu" component={Fmenu}} />
      
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

E após fazer o login ou o registro, vai ser enviado para o Fmenu e lá eu gostaria que não tivesse mais a seta de voltar do React Native...
Aliás, estivesse tentando e olhando algumas postagens do fórum e não encontrei nenhum que conseguisse me ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar dentro da Screen onde você não quer o botão voltar a opção "options" e dentro dela adicionar "headerLeft" com o valor null.

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    headerLeft: null
  }}
/>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headerleft

Comment: Eita! Muito obrigado, agora foi! <3